# EFI+GPT, вин10+бунта. При перезагрузке из винды грузится винда, минуя grub menu. Как исправить?

Tags: grub, dual-boot, uefi, gpt

Все это пока живет в виртуалбоксе. С GPT раньше не сталкивался. Граб ставил в EFI раздел. При старте машины вижу меню grub. При ребуте из бунты -- grub. При ребуте из винды сразу грузится винда. В чем причина, и как это победить?

[image: grub menu]

Comment: Выключить быстрый запуск? https://remontka.pro/fast-startup-windows-10/

Comment: в настройках UEFI отключить пункт с загрузкой Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, причина была в виртуалбоксе и в версии 6.1 она устранена. В процессе ковыряния обнаружил, что UEFI не сохраняет настройки порядка загрузки. В 6.1 работает.